# How to change DataTables in rdlc reports programmatically

Tags: c#, database-connection, rdlc

I have a following problem. I made an application that generates rdlc reports for one of my clients. I used TableAdapters to fill the DataTables that I use in those reports. The problem is that my client has a new database and he wants to be able to use that application to generate reports from both the old and the new one. I thought it was possible to change the connection that my TableAdapters use so that they would just take the data from the database that my client selects (both databases have identical schema's) but I was told that that cannot be done. So is it possible to change the DataTable that rdlc report uses?
How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign any datatable to rdlc at run time using following code.

```
        DataTable dtTest =obj.SelectDepartment(1);//Here I am selecting the data from DB

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        reportViewer1.Visible = true;
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
        reportViewer1.Reset();
        reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        LocalReport rep = reportViewer1.LocalReport;
        rep.Refresh();

        rep.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report.rdlc";//Provide full path
        rds.Name = "DataSet1_tblAdapter";//Provide refrerence to data set which is used to   design the rdlc. (DatasetName_TableAdapterName)
        rds.Value = dtTest;

        rep.DataSources.Add(rds);
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve this problem in the meantime, and it is almost identical to your solution.

Comment: required reference: using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it should be fine to change your data source for the report dynamically

```
  rptView.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("MyReportName")
  rptView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("DataSource", "ObjectSource"))
```

Sorry bout the code being VB.net, I know your question is marked C#, but it should be similar enough

Edit:

If you wanted some Parameters

```
    dim listOfParams = new List(of ReportParameter);
    listOfParams.Add(new ReportParameter("Param1", myValue.toString()))
    listOfParams.Add(new ReportParameter("Param2", myOtherValue.toString()))


    Me.rptView.LocalReport.GetParameters(listOfParams)
```

Just coded that straight so it might well be a mix of C# and VB.net

Comment: It doesn't matter if its in VB, there are translators on the Web. Only one thing, I see you use Server class, but this is a desktop application, so what is the equivalent?

Comment: I haven't tried this out, but I imagine just a string pointing to the rdlc file, something like "~/MyReports/Report1.rdlc"

Comment: One question rises - will the parameters bind themselves (provided that they have the same name as the prior ones) or do I have to do that programmatically (and how would that be done)