# C# RDLC Report - dynamic data

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have created a Form1, on it is a reportviewer.

In the form's code I have:

```
reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"..\..\Report1.rdlc";
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = @"..\..\Report1.rdlc";
```

This will link in Report1.rdlc - this works fine.  I would like to do this in code so I can later link in Report2 through Report299 onto the same Form.  I can add a line to the report and when it runs the line shows up on the form - so that is working.

But! then I go to the Report Data pane and add some data to the report.  I have tried a lot of different ways to do this, embedded, shared, modeled, just about anything I could find on the net. But I always get some form of:

A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source "DataSet1"

Oddly it works fine if I dont do the ReportPath code above, but rather just link it on the ReportViewer.  But I was hoping not to make hundreds of Reportviewers.

Is there any way to somehow instantiate a data source programmically?

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124047/how-to-change-datatables-in-rdlc-reports-programmatically

Comment: no luck there - comes up with "The report definition for report \Report1 has not been specified.  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.